# Error when run docker pull "net/http: request cancelled while waiting for connection"

Tags: docker, vps

I'm learning docker and installing it in my VPS by this [post](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/centos/). But it don't work
when I run
`docker pull hello-world` it causes errors like this.

```sh
Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

[image]

And this is result when i run `docker info`

```sh
Client:
 Debug Mode: false

Server:
 Containers: 0
  Running: 0
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 0
 Images: 0
 Server Version: 19.03.5
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: extfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Native Overlay Diff: true
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: b34a5c8af56e510852c35414db4c1f4fa6172339
 runc version: 3e425f80a8c931f88e6d94a8c831b9d5aa481657
 init version: fec3683
 Security Options:
  seccomp
   Profile: default
 Kernel Version: 3.10.0-1062.4.3.el7.x86_64
 Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 4
 Total Memory: 3.7GiB
 Name: vps24129.sdns.vn
 ID: 3L4E:BKSU:F2PQ:BGCX:L77Z:TJJ7:CVJD:EZHQ:HCNW:SEL2:2IRR:ZHSF
 Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
 Debug Mode: false
 HTTP Proxy: http://:::443
 HTTPS Proxy: http://10.0.0.0:3128
 No Proxy: localhost,127.0.0.0/8,docker-registry.somecorporation.com
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false

WARNING: API is accessible on http://127.0.0.1:2375 without encryption.
         Access to the remote API is equivalent to root access on the host. Refer
         to the 'Docker daemon attack surface' section in the documentation for
         more information: https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/security/#docker-daemon-attack-surface
```

I tried some ways on google like disable firewall, setup proxy, reset vps, reinstall docker but it still didn't work. Hope everyone help me

Comment: What happens when you try `docker info`?

Comment: Maybe you are running behind a firewall that prevents access to docker hub?

Comment: im just update my question, can you help me ?